# Position Sticky to affect nested children as it does siblings

Tags: css, position, css-position

I'm trying to increase the visibility of headers in blog articles. One idea I have is to use `position:sticky` on the header so the header elements (H1, H2, H3, etc) are always visible at the top of the screen. The problem, is these elements are by definition nested.

Here is a jfiddle showing the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/81rxzros/

**Is there a way so the children elements "push" the parent elements off the screen as if they were all sibling elements?**

The goal is for all the header tags (H1, H2, H3, H4) to *only* have *the most recent* header "stuck" at the top of the page. The header before it should be "pushed" off the screen, even if the "most recent header" is nested *within* the header preceding it.

The same way the "*four header*" elements behave in the jfiddle above.

Edit:  I know I can mimic this behavior by setting a background on each H# tag and setting them all to the same height -- so the most recent  element "covers" the  element before it. But I don't particularly want to set the H6 elements to the same height as the H1 element.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your question clearly.But I think `Z-index`can take a part there.[On your given link](https://jsfiddle.net/81rxzros/) If you make 
`h4{
Z-index:1;
}`
Then it will push its parents also and will come front.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I added more context in the question. Let me know if this helps. I'm afraid your a answer isn't quite what I am looking for -- the question is not about which of the header tags appear "above" the other, it is more an issue of them acting as siblings so that only *one* header is "stuck" to the top at any given time.

Comment: Yes, Now I can understand, What you exactly want to know? Maybe it's not possible by using CSS.But using javascript.It can be handled.If there have ways to do it by CSS, I have no idea about that.But It's a good question.Waiting for anybody who could answer it.Thanks